# Hiding part of the object

Tags: rendering, masking

im trying to hide part of my object(B) on render. Hidden part is defined by other object(A) that covers it on camera view(z axis). Is there any good solution for that? Thanks!

[image: Example Attachment with description]

Answer (score 2):

Give object A an [Holdout](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/holdout.html) material.

That will only work if "Transparent" is enabled in Render Properties/Film, so in case you want a solid background, you'll need to add it in compositing.[image]